# How do I use the logged in user on the sales table, in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm making a website with ASP.NET in C# and I am using a SQL database with different users/logins.
Every user is supposed to input data into a database table on the website and the users should only see their input not the whole table.

I have  two tables, one for login/user table and a Sales table, so I have a userID in both tables, what I need is for the userID to fill in automatically in the sales table on the logged in user, and yes I have made a relationship between the tables.
How do I make this work?

I think this is how it should work maybe I'm thinking wrong here if so please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is very confusing.

The way I understand it is: When your user comes to your website, they will fill a form (assuming user have logged in). Now, when the user fills the form, you need that data to be filled in both your "User" & "Sales" table.

The user should only be seeing the information entered by him/her.

If my understanding is correct, then you need to create a stored procedure  which take the data from the form (your front end will pass that to your SP). Then, in your SP, you insert the relevant data in both the tables (user id being same). After that, just make a select keeping the current session user id in the WHERE condition.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking your time but, No I only need data to be filled in the "Sales" table. I have made it possible to store data there by a form, and show the data by a gridview. What I need is when a user is logged in to my website and he/her fills this form and store it in the database, he/her will only see his/her input in the database. Now everyone can see all the input made by everyone.

Comment: But this is also what Taher says - you select the userID from the user table and use that ID in the "where" clause when querying the sales table.

Comment: Yes, that what I said. You will have your user id in the session I believe. Use that in the select query.

Hint: Have a column "CreatedBy" in your table, and store the userId of the person who is entering that data (current logged in user). Then in your select query, give "WHERE CreatedBy = @UserId"

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Taher, I tried "WHERE CreatedBy = @UserId" but i get "Unable to parse query text." I've tried in different ways but without results, any idea why or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is when I am logged in and input data into the "sales" table the database is not aware that I am that UserID which I'm logged in as.

Comment: You need to pass the user id to your stored procedure. If you have a log in mechanism (which ideally you should) then you can store the user id in Session after successful authentication. Then call your stored procedure by passing that user id from session.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do some impersonation probably.  You should not be doing this though.  In your application layer you should handle security, not at database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you have correct relation between different table based on `userID` also then you can easily restrict the data you want to show & insert data in respective table along with `userID`.

If you are using [ASP.Net membership](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) then you can that if it is custom membership then you can store the loggedin userID in session variable & CRUD query based on this userID.

Before i can help you with query it would be great to have table structure along with some dummy data would be great.

Hope this gets you started

Comment: No im not using ASP.NET membership, I created my own create user with the drag and drop tool 'CreateUserWizard' I dont really know how to show you the table structure :/